# preg match for capturing before and after a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to extract the number (given in bold) from the rss feed link which I have. How can I achieve it using `preg_match()`?

```
....com/photo/51671645.cms
```

Comment: let see what have you tried until now

Comment: will the `bold` part always integer?

Comment: yes...always an integer

Answer (score -1):

Just use this simple pattern `com/photo/(\d+).cms`:

```
preg_match('|com/photo/(\d+).cms|', 'com/photo/51671645.cms', $matches);
$number = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Why prefix and postfix the expression with '|' - that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Try to remove this `|` delimiter and you will see `PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: your regex should start with '/' and end with '/'

Comment: You have problem with your knowledge about `php regexp`. Try to read manual:  http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Actually, no I don't...the 2nd sentence on that page state "Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~). The following are all examples of valid delimited patterns."....The examples that follow DO NOT include '|' - which means 'OR' in PCRE.

Comment: Try to read first two sentence again `When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.`. So `|` is non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character and you can use it. If there are no this sybmol in manual example it doesn't mean that this symbol is deprecated for use as delimiter

Comment: In any case you can run code and check any regex pattern into preg_match function If You do not trust the official php.net manual

Comment: alexander.polomodov - thanks! - you are absolutely correct! I have learnt something today from you.